# Active window switching oddity with multiple workspaces and applications in full screen mode

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

In Ubuntu 16.04 with workspaces enabled I'm having trouble getting applications switcher/workspaces to behave in a friendly manner if some windows are in full screen mode.

Say I have two workspaces A and B.
A has two windows open: browser and terminal 1 in full screen mode.
B has one window open: another terminal 2 in full screen mode.

I leave workspace A with browser window being active and move to workspace B to work in a terminal 2.
Then I move back to A but end up in a state where (1) no particular window is active, (2) terminal 1 is at the foreground, NOT the browser.

Then I need to either Alt-Tab to make terminal 1 active or click in it, and Alt-Tab to get back to the browser.

This does not seem to be the property of the application switcher --- I've tried the default plugin one, "applications switcher" and "static application switcher" with no luck.

The problem does not occur if applications are not in full screen mode --- if they are in maximized state everything is fine.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem, and this was present in 15.04 aalso